# how to update permalink column is null using permalink_fu in rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console, permalinks, rails-console, permalink-fu

How to update column permalink  null using permalink_fu in rails console?

Let say i have a table_name article,the column is title and permalink. 
I want to update only the null permalink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

> rails c
>
> Business.where(:permalink =>nil).each(&:save)